# How can I or my app know that Chrome is discarding indexed db items?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, local-storage, indexeddb

I have an app which has recently started to randomly lose indexeddb items. By "lose" I mean they are confirmed as having been saved, but days later, are no longer present.

My hypothesis is that Chrome is discarding indexeddb items because the disk is full.

My question is specifically, are there any events that my app can listen for, or any Chrome log entries that I can refer to in order to confirm this is the case. NB. I'm not looking to fix the problem, I am only looking for ways in which I can detect it.

Comment: Are you sure about that didn't you install an extension like [IndexedDB cleaner](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/indexeddb-cleaner/bkbkgpcacphidgmpbfcapoillheakfpi)?

Comment: @M.Rostami I'm sure. I have no extensions installed

Comment: I think you need IndexedDB Observer. These links may help you if I got what you meant. [Link-01](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/indexeddb-observers/) - [Link-02](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1pdEjzEcMZSrxG6GLUo8CCB5Ej2lAUns6kiDczbH9r2Q/mobilebasic)

Comment: you basically cannot do this, the browser can delete indexedDB data at any time, typically due to reaching the maximum allowed storage size

Comment: @Josh I know it can. My question is how can a user or my app know for sure that this is happening?

Comment: A browser is supposed to evict the entire origin, so simply polling for one item you always set would normally be enough to decide to rebuild. Maybe this is something else like session info being copied between browsers, or not checking that updates were successful?

Comment: This project from Github might be helpful. It is trying to achieve what you want but it has been some time since update: https://github.com/WICG/indexed-db-observers/blob/gh-pages/EXPLAINER.md.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Each application can query how much data is stored or how much more
>   space is available for the app by calling queryUsageAndQuota() method
>   of Quota API.[See](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2011/11/Quota-Management-API-Fast-Facts)

You can use periodic [BackgroundSync](https://github.com/WICG/BackgroundSync/tree/master/explainers)
to estimate the used and free space allocated to temporary usage [using](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5630353511284736):

```
// index.html
navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(registration => {
  registration.periodicSync.register('estimate-storage', {
    // Minimum interval at which the sync may fire.
    minInterval: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
  });
});

// service_worker.js

self.addEventListener('periodicsync', event => {
  if (event.tag == 'estimate-storage') {
    event.waitUntil(estimateAndNotify());
  }
});

To estimate use the method: navigator.storage.estimate()//returns a Promise which resolves with {usage, quota} values in bytes.
```

> When TEMPORARY storage quota is exceeded, all the data (incl.
>   AppCache, IndexedDB, WebSQL, File System API) stored for oldest used
>   origin gets deleted.

You can switch to unlimitedStorage or persistent storage.

Comment: I suspect the answer to my question as asked is that it's not possible. However, using the Quota API as described in this answer seems to provide the best alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how will it work in real life

> This feature was initially still somewhat experimental.

but here https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/06/persistent-storage you can find that

> This is still under development [...] the goal is to make users are aware of “persistent” data before clearing it [...] you can presume that “persistent” means your data won’t get cleared without the user being **explicitly informed** and directly in control of that deletion.

Which can answer you clarification in comments that you are looking for a way

> how can a user **or** my app know for sure that this is happening

So, don't know about your app, but user *maybe* can get a notification. At least the page is of 2016 year. Something must have been done by now.

Answer (score 0):

You may refer to [Browser storage limits and eviction criteria](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Browser_storage_limits_and_eviction_criteria) article on MDN.

> My hypothesis is that Chrome is discarding indexeddb items because the disk is full

According to this article your hypothesis seems to be true.

Now one of the ways to confirm this could be to save unique ids of items that are confirmed in a persistent storage - (this will have very small size compared to your actual data) and periodically compare whether all items are there in your indexeddb.

You might also want to refer to [best practices](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/instant-and-offline/web-storage/indexeddb-best-practices).
and finally this comments

> I think you need IndexedDB Observer. These links may help you if I got what you meant. [Link-01](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/indexeddb-observers/) - [Link-02](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1pdEjzEcMZSrxG6GLUo8CCB5Ej2lAUns6kiDczbH9r2Q/mobilebasic)

might be helpful.